# d3.js Add labels in Chord diagram

Tags: d3.js, label, chord-diagram

I am new to this kind of chord visualization. I am working  on a sample http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006:

[image]

I would like to add "black", "blonde","brown","red"  as labels in the respective chord. How is this possible.

I tried something like this but is not working:

```
var textLabel = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['Black','Blonde','Brown','Red']);

svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.groups)
   .enter()
    .append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return  fill(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
svg.append("g").append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .attr("dy", 15)
    .append("svg:textPath")
    .text(function(d,i) { return textLabel(i+1); })
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557720/add-labels-to-d3-chord-diagram)?

Comment: Yes, based on that i tried to add textpath element but seems i have missed something.

Comment: BTW you can clean up that `if`/`else if` block by using a scale. `var textLabel = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['Black','Blonde','Brown','Red'])` then just `textLabel(i+1)`

Comment: Christopher, i have replaced the code and saved the same, but still i am not able to display the text in the chord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to use the `enter` selection and also do not link the `svg:textPath` to an actual path in the SGV. To do this the path you want the text to follow needs to have been given an `id` attribute and you need to reference this in the `textPath` with an `href` attribute.

So you want to add the id attribute to the path you want the text to follow

```
.attr("id", function(d, i){return "group-" + i;})
```

You then want to do something like this to add textPath elements

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
        .data(chord.groups)
    .enter()
    .append("sgv:text")
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("dy", 15)
        .append("svg:textPath")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i){return "#group-" + i;})
            .text(function(d,i) {return textLabel(i+1);});
```

Finally with the colour black you will probably want to invert the text so you don't end up with black on black text.

```
            .filter(function(d, i){return i === 0 ? true : false;})
            .attr("style", "fill:white;");
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine.