# How to add labels into the arc of a chord diagram in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

This is my chord diagram with d3.js version 4 (based on [this chart](https://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/d2720fdaab1123df73f4806360a09c9e) in v3). You can run it or just have a look at the image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Chord Diagramm</title>

    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- bootstrap 4(!) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        fill: #2B2B2B;
        cursor: default;
      }

      @media (min-width: 600px) {
        #chart{
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Chord Diagramm </h1>
    <div id = "chart"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var margin = {left:90, top:90, right:90, bottom:90},
    width =  1000 - margin.left - margin.right, // more flexibility: Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000)
    height =  1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom, // same: Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000)
    innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39,
    outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

  var names = ["Test1","Test2","AMO-DB","YouTube","Twitter", "Google+", "Pflegeratgeber" ,"O-Mag","RuV"],
    colors = ["#301E1E", "#083E77", "#342350", "#567235", "#8B161C", "#DF7C00"],
    opacityDefault = 0.8;

  var matrix = [
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], //Test1
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], //Test2
    [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], //Hawkeye
    [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1], //The Hulk
    [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], //Iron Man
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1], //Iron Man
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0] //Thor //Thor
  ];

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////// Create scale and layout functions //////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(d3.range(names.length))
    .range(colors);

  var chord = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(.15)
    .sortChords(d3.descending)

    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius*1.01)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var path = d3.ribbon()
  .radius(innerRadius);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// Create SVG //////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2 + margin.left) + "," + (height/2 + margin.top) + ")")
  .datum(chord(matrix));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Draw outer Arcs /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var outerArcs = svg.selectAll("g.group")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "group")
  .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
  .on("mouseout", fade(opacityDefault))

  // text popups
  .on("click", mouseoverChord)
  .on("mouseout", mouseoutChord);

outerArcs.append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.index); })
  .attr("d", arc);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// Append names ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Append the label names on the outside
outerArcs.append("text")
  .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "titles")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
    + "translate(" + (outerRadius + 10) + ")"
    + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
  })
  .text(function(d,i) { return names[i]; });


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Draw inner chords ///////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

svg.selectAll("path.chord")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "chord")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.source.index); })
  .style("opacity", opacityDefault)
  .attr("d", path);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Extra Functions /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function popup() {
  return function(d,i) {
    console.log("love");
  };
}//popup

//Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(d,i) {
    svg.selectAll("path.chord")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
    .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}//fade

  //Highlight hovered over chord
function mouseoverChord(d,i) {

  //Decrease opacity to all
  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", 0.1);
  //Show hovered over chord with full opacity
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
        .style("opacity", 1);

  //Define and show the tooltip over the mouse location
  $(this).popover({
    //placement: 'auto top',
    title: 'test',
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    animation: false,
    offset: "20px -100px",
    followMouse: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return "<p style='font-size: 11px; text-align: center;'><span style='font-weight:900'>"  +
           "</span> text <span style='font-weight:900'>"  +
           "</span> folgt hier <span style='font-weight:900'>" + "</span> movies </p>"; }
  });
  $(this).popover('show');
}
//Bring all chords back to default opacity
function mouseoutChord(d) {
  //Hide the tooltip
  $('.popover').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })
  //Set opacity back to default for all
  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", opacityDefault);
  }      //function mouseoutChord
  </script>
</html>
```

I tried to follow this example: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/9eadf19bd2976653fa50 and also found a similar thread here: [d3.js Add labels in Chord diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513682/d3-js-add-labels-in-chord-diagram)

However, I can't wrap my head around how to integrate it into my code. Any help really appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can approach it like this:

1. Add an `id` to the paths while you're appending them based on which group it is in.

   ```
   outerArcs.append("path")
     .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.index); })
     .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + d.index; }) //add id here
     .attr("d", arc);
   ```
2. Append the text directly to the `path` and then use `textpath` which places it inside the arc like the following:

   ```
   outerArcs.append("text")
        .attr("x", 6)
       .attr("dy", 15)
     .append("textPath")
       .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#group" + d.index; })
       .text(function(chords, i){return names[i];})
       .style("fill", "white");
   ```

Working code here - https://jsfiddle.net/rjonean4/

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one quick follow-up question/note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href states xlink is deprecated. I just kept ```href``` and it seems to work as well.

Comment: Last note: how is it possible to center the text? Thanks for all your help :)